# Code running correctly only when variables defined outside of class in Arduino IDE

Tags: c++, arduino, stepper

I'm very new to C++, I'm writing a code to control stepper motors using the micros() function on Arduino IDE. When I run the code as is, the stepper motor does not turn. While the motor runs expectedly when I assign the variables outside the class instead of in the class.

NON-WORKING CODE:

```
const int DIR_PIN = 5; // direction
const int STEP_PIN = 2; // step

class steppercontrol {
private:
  unsigned long currenttime;
  unsigned long prevtime;
  int pulsecount;
  int stepcount;
  int delaytime;
  bool pulse;

public:
  void setspeed(int speed){ 
    delaytime = speed;
  }
  void run(int targetstep){
    while (stepcount < targetstep){
      currenttime = micros();
      if (currenttime - prevtime > delaytime){ // compare time passed to desired delay
        pulsecount ++; 
        if(pulsecount % 2 == 0){stepcount++;} // 2 pulses in 1 step

        pulse = pulse == LOW ? HIGH : LOW;
        digitalWrite(STEP_PIN, pulse);
        prevtime = currenttime;
      }
    }
  }
};

void setup() {
  pinMode(STEP_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DIR_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(DIR_PIN, HIGH);
  steppercontrol stepper;

  stepper.setspeed(1000);
  stepper.run(1600);
}

void loop() {
}
```

CODE WITH VARIABLES OUTSIDE CLASS, WORKING:

```
const int DIR_PIN = 5; // direction
const int STEP_PIN = 2; // step

unsigned long currenttime;
unsigned long prevtime;
int pulsecount;
int stepcount;
int delaytime;
bool pulse;

class steppercontrol {
public:
  void setspeed(int speed){ 
    delaytime = speed;
  }
  void run(int targetstep){
    while (stepcount < targetstep){
      currenttime = micros();
      if (currenttime - prevtime > delaytime){ // compare time passed to desired delay
        pulsecount ++; 
        if(pulsecount % 2 == 0){stepcount++;} // 2 pulses in 1 step

        pulse = pulse == LOW ? HIGH : LOW;
        digitalWrite(STEP_PIN, pulse);
        prevtime = currenttime;
      }
    }
  }
};

void setup() {
  pinMode(STEP_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DIR_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(DIR_PIN, HIGH);
  steppercontrol stepper;

  stepper.setspeed(1000);
  stepper.run(1600);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: In your non-working code, it looks like you neglected to initialized your member variables. You don't do that in the "working" code either, but there they are globals, so implicitly start out as 0's.

Comment: `steppercontrol stepper;` -- You should have written a default constructor that initializes the member variables.  This issue has nothing to do with `arduino` or `stepper`, and everything to do with not properly constructing objects with member variables (i.e. general C++).  `while (stepcount < targetstep)` -- debug your code in `run`, and don't be shocked if one or both of these variables have garbage values, all due to not being initialized.

Comment: You will see [in this simple example](https://godbolt.org/z/bzKzxjYWo) that `stepcount` and `pulsecount` have indeterminate values in the `run` function.  Also, if you take that example at godbolt and recompiled it, you may get those values to be 0, but then that's the point -- you don't know what the values will be if you don't actually initialize them.